# Installing Fedora 20 repos

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

I have recently installed Fedora 20 on my laptop. For the first thing, I tried to add Rpmfusion , Russianfedora to it; but it was failed. In the terminal I entered this:

```
su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck  http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
```

and got this error:

```
File contains parsing errors: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo
    [line  5]:     name=A fast downloader plugin for yum

    [line  7]:     baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hedayat/yum-fast-downloader/fedora-20/noarch/

    [line  9]:     enabled=1

    [line 11]:     skip_if_unavailable=1

    [line 13]:     gpgcheck=1

    [line 15]:     gpgkey=http://hedayat.fedorapeople.org/gpg/hedayat-rpm-gpg-key

    [line 19]:     name=A fast downloader plugin for yum – Source

    [line 21]:     baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hedayat/yum-fast-downloader/fedora-20/SRPMS

    [line 23]:     enabled=0

    [line 25]:     skip_if_unavailable=1

    [line 27]:     gpgcheck=1

    [line 29]:     gpgkey=http://hedayat.fedorapeople.org/gpg/hedayat-rpm-gpg-key
```

Then I tried to add russianfedora repo using this command:

```
[root@dhcppc0 Daniel]# su -c 'yum install --nogpgcheck htttp://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/free/fedora/russianfedora-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm htttp://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/nonfree/fedora/russianfedora-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm'
```

I got this error:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit


File contains parsing errors: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo
    [line  5]:     name=A fast downloader plugin for yum

    [line  7]:     baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hedayat/yum-fast-downloader/fedora-20/noarch/

    [line  9]:     enabled=1

    [line 11]:     skip_if_unavailable=1

    [line 13]:     gpgcheck=1

    [line 15]:     gpgkey=http://hedayat.fedorapeople.org/gpg/hedayat-rpm-gpg-key

    [line 19]:     name=A fast downloader plugin for yum – Source

    [line 21]:     baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hedayat/yum-fast-downloader/fedora-20/SRPMS

    [line 23]:     enabled=0

    [line 25]:     skip_if_unavailable=1

    [line 27]:     gpgcheck=1

    [line 29]:     gpgkey=http://hedayat.fedorapeople.org/gpg/hedayat-rpm-gpg-key
```

Why am I getting parsing errors in `file://///etc/yum/repos.d/fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo` that prevent me from adding repositories?

**See What included in fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo**

```
[fedora-yum-fast-downloader]

name=A fast downloader plugin for yum

baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hedayat/yum-fast-downloader/fedora-$releasever/noarch/

enabled=1

skip_if_unavailable=1

gpgcheck=1

gpgkey=http://hedayat.fedorapeople.org/gpg/hedayat-rpm-gpg-key

[fedora-yum-fast-downloader-source]

name=A fast downloader plugin for yum – Source

baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hedayat/yum-fast-downloader/fedora-$releasever/SRPMS

enabled=0

skip_if_unavailable=1

gpgcheck=1

gpgkey=http://hedayat.fedorapeople.org/gpg/hedayat-rpm-gpg-key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your helpful suggestions!
when I got that by entering every command in Terminal the answer is a Parsing Error within the yum-fast-downloader.repo so I delete the file from the etc/yum.repos.d directory. then I got that by entering the same commands I got an error suggesting another parsing error in the **skype repo file**, so i delete it too. After all, I re-command for installing yum-fast-downloader.repo, then upgrade fedora repos. Now the problem is solved, and all the programs can be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to determine from your error message the reason why the `fedora-yum-fast-downloader` repository file is failing to parse. However, I believe you can work around your error and successfully add your repositories as follows:

Whenever you invoke the `yum` command for any reason, include the following parameter:

`--disablerepo=fedora-yum-fast-downloader`

*For example*, to add the russianfedora repos, the command would be as follows:

```
yum install --nogpgcheck --disablerepo=fedora-yum-fast-downloader http://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/free/fedora/russianfedora-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/nonfree/fedora/russianfedora-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

This will **temporarily** make `yum` stop trying to parse the `fedora-yum-fast-downloader` repository, which should at least *avoid* the parsing error in the `.repo` file, allowing you to proceed. The workaround is imperfect, because the ideal case would be for you to look into that file `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo` with a text editor, and to figure out if there are some invalid characters that violate the `.repo` file format, and fix them.

If you think you can do that, you would be able to solve your problem "permanently" by doing so, and you would also be able to take advantage of the yum fast downloader plugin, which can improve the download speed of your `yum` in some circumstances (as the plugin's name suggests).

**Edit**: It looks like you also have *three* `t`s in your `htttp` URIs for the russianfedora repo. Make sure you change them to `http`, or you'll encounter yet more errors.

**Edit 2**: I think the newlines between each line in your `fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo` file are causing the parse error. To check, please do the following:

1. Rename the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo` to something else, or move it to another directory. You can `mv` it to your home directory to get it out of the way; that is my recommendation.
2. Run `wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/hedayat/yum-fast-downloader/fedora-yum-fast-downloader.repo` as root.
3. Try your repos again.

By fetching the repo file from the repo itself, you'll be able to eliminate the chance that your file is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. I entered three t s in http urls because I didn't have enough reputations for asking my question.

Comment: Now, I just opened the file fedora-fats-downloader.repo using gedit. you can see the text down to my question.

Comment: @Daniel -- see my "Edit 2" comment.

Comment: thank you allquixotic, I did it, but the error was still on. by removing the yum-fast-downloader.repo and skype.repo my problem was solved. thank u again for your support.

Answer (score 0):

1. open terminal and switch to root using `su`
2. Download the **rpmfusion** repo definition file using
   `wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-20.noarch.rpm`
   and install it through `yum localinstall --nogpgcheck ./rpmfusion-free-release-20.noarch.rpm`
3. Download the **russianfedora** repo definition file using
   `wget http://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/free/fedora/russianfedora-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm` (you've got too much "t"s in the http in your russianfedora address) and install it through `yum localinstall --nogpgcheck ./russianfedora-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm`

After this magic you can use rpmfusion and russianfedora repos.

Comment: If you read his comment, he said he put three "t"s in the http URLs because he didn't have enough reputation for including links (an anti-spam feature of the site). Your answer is basically a re-hashing of the original question without providing any additional information.

Comment: @allquixotic I think that installing it all by localinstall would help.

Comment: thank u all so much because of your support. all what matters is the state of cooperation.